# Command handler Telethon

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telethon

I started building a bot with the Telethon library but couldn't find a clean way to separate the command from the text.

For example, with the `python-telegram-bot` library, I can retrieve the first argument after the command like this:

```
def test(update, context):
    arg_1 = context.args[0]
    print(arg_1) # Prints the first word after the command
```

So... There's a way to make something like this using Telethon? (I'm using this piece of code to split text from command but I think this method is not really good):

```
txt = event.message.message.lower()
try:
    txt.split("!raw ")[1]
    text = event.message.message[4:]
except Exception as e:
    text = ""
    

if text:
    do_something()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a handler defined in the following way:

```py
@client.on(events.NewMessage(pattern=r'!raw (\w+)'))
async def handler(event):
    ...
```

You can then access the `event.pattern_match`:

```py
arg = event.pattern_match.group(1)
print(arg)  # first word
```

However, using `.split()` is also okay:

```py
parts = event.raw_text.split()
if len(parts) > 1:
    arg = parts[1]
```

(And you can also build a better UX, by telling the user when they used the command wrong.)